# My JavaScript countdown does not update. Why?

Tags: javascript, css, countdown

I'm trying to put a countdown on my website according to this example: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq

Here's the code on my page:

```
var timestamp_today = Math.floor(Date.now() /1000);
var timestamp_event = 1511679600;
var diff = timestamp_event-timestamp_today;
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + diff*1000);
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

HTML

```
<div id="countdown">
    <div>
        <span class="days"></span>
         <div class="smalltext">Jours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="hours"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Heures</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Secondes</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that my divs are blank: no numbers whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any js code inserting the js variables in the html!

Comment: well for starters, you're calling `initializeClock()` and that isn't defined.

Comment: The JS functions, like initializeClock() are on the link I gave in my message

Comment: In your code nowhere you are Setting the values for Hours, Minutes and second.

Comment: I calculated the remaining time to the event with the `diff` timestamp

Comment: Please share how your code is now. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Okay I don't get what's happening here. I copy-pasted to your website exactly the code I have, and it works. But it doesn't on my local page. https://jsfiddle.net/6aq21fbu/

Comment: I just opened your link and countdown seems to work properly...

Comment: it does, but this is what i get the local pages on my computer http://imgur.com/zicBobJ

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `<script>` before the `</body>` closes

```
<body>
  <nav class="midnight">...
  ...</section>
  <script>
    function getTimeRemain....
    ...ializeClock('countdown', deadline);
  <script>
</body>
```

But if your `<script>` is in an external file inside head it has to go the next way

```
window.onload=function(){
  function getTimeRemain....
  ...ializeClock('countdown', deadline);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @narfi a pleasure to help you